# Does anybody know how to detect orientation change for Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, nativescript

I have created two xml files for a screen. one named "login-page.port.xml" and the other one is "login-page.land.xaml".

Is there a way to programmatically detect orientation change within the application?

Thanks,
Keks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to detect orientation change in the application.  The easiest method is in the page you want to get the orientation; add the loaded and unloaded events to your page.xml files:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" unloaded="pageUnloaded">
```

In your page.js file; add code like this:

```
var application=require('application');
exports.pageLoaded = function() {
  application.on(application.orientationChangedEvent, setOrientation);
};

exports.pageUnloaded = function() {
  application.off(application.orientationChangedEvent, setOrientation);
}

function setOrientation(args) {
   // Will console out the new Orientation
   console.log(args.newValue);
}
```

A couple notes;
1. You want to add & remove the event listener as you enter and exit the page; otherwise the listener is global and will continue to fire when the orientation changes even when you are on another page.
2. You can add multiple listeners to this event, so again if you don't remove the listener, then each time you re-load this page you will add ANOTHER copy of this listener to the group and so it will fire as many times as you have added it.
3. On android in v1.6.1 their is a bug in the orientation firing.  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1656  (Basically if you start in Landscape, rotate it won't detect it.  The issue has the patch that I've applied manually to my code).

---

Now Looking at your actual example; are you aware that at least as of version 1.6.x of NativeScript it will only load the XML for which ever orientation it currently is set as; but it will NOT load the other orientation's xml when you rotate.  So, if you are in Landscape; enter the screen then rotate it will still be using the Landscape xml file.

---

Now with all that said you might seriously consider looking at the [nativescript-orientation](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-orientation) plugin which I am the author of, this plugin simplifies dealing with screen orientation and allows you to only have ONE .xml file and then change things via css.

Comment: I should probably state for completeness; you can also add a single application.on(...) to your app.js file if the handler is GLOBAL in nature.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Nathanael! :)

Comment: Note that if you want to use any of the current "Page" content you need to pass the "this" to the attaching:

application.on(application.orientationChangedEvent, setOrientation, this);

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov - `this` isn't needed except in the case of calling into a class function.   In the example above, when it calls the setOrientation() function, the setOrientation() function has full access to any other function that is in that same JS file.

Comment: @Nathanael I know this just added my comment for clarity since many people will use this in TypeSript projects where the this will be desired.

Comment: @Nathanael Is it possible to disable orientation globaly ? ( in other words , how do I prevent landscape ?) is there any `args.cancel()?` method ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You can easily disable rotation programatically/on demand with the nativescript-orientation plugin.

Answer (score 2):

### For those using [angular2-nativescript](/questions/tagged/angular2-nativescript) [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript)

Please refer to the [on method found in the documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_.html#on)

> on(event: "orientationChanged", callback: function, thisArg?: any):
>   any Defined in application/application.d.ts:232 This event is raised
>   the orientation of the current device has changed.
>
> Parameters
>
> event: "orientationChanged"
>
> callback: function
>
> (args: OrientationChangedEventData): void Parameters
>
> args: OrientationChangedEventData
>
> Returns void Optional thisArg: any
>
> Returns any

### Example in use:

```
@Component({
    selector: "Test"
    //templateUrl, styleUrls, etc... 
})
export class TestComponent{
   constructor(){
     on("orientationChanged", this.onOrientationChanged)
   }

   public onOrientationChanged = (evt) => {
      console.log("Orientation has changed !");
      console.log(evt.eventName); // orientationChanged
      console.log(evt.newValue); //landscape or portrait
    };

}
```

Comment: should from `application` module i.e `import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";` and then call `app.on('orientationChanged', (dat)=> {})`