# How to reload a page with a different XML template when orientation changes?

Tags: android, nativescript

how to reload a page (with a new template) when the orientation of the device changes?
I want a different layout in landscape mode. This is in NativeScript, not Java.

the correct xml file is selected if i arrive at the page in landscape, but if i change orientation, nothing gets reloaded.

Note that this is not a question of refreshing the CSS, it is a different XML file needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NativeScript solution:**

First you need to tie into the orientation event.  You have a couple ways you can tie into that event.

The first and easiest method is to install the nativescript-orientation plugin, it ties into the event globally and then it will just automatically run your exported function on each of the current page called orientation, each time the orientation changes.
To Install:

```
tns plugin install nativescript-orientation
```

Open your app.js file and add at the top of the file;

```
require('nativescript-orientation');
```

Then by creating:

```
exports.orientation = function(args) {
  if (args.landscaped) { /* do landscape stuff */ }
  else { /* do port */
};
```

on any page you want to be notified that the orientation changed, it will be called on those pages that have that function and you can handle the event how you need to.

---

However, if you prefer to not use a plugin, you can directly tie into the orientation event yourself by doing:

```
var application = require('application');
exports.onNavigateTo = function() {
  application.on(application.orientationChangedEvent,myOrientationFunction);
}

exports.onNavigateFrom = function() {
  application.off(application.orientationChangedEvent, myOrientationFunction);

function myOrientationFunction(args) {
  // We have an orientation event
}
```

However you must ask to be notified of the event when your page first open and you must remove your self from the notification when your page closes.  This is a lot of extra code per page that the plugin above just handles for you. Please note when you are doing this yourself you also need to to add the NavigateTo/NavigatedFrom to the <Page> tag in your Declarative UI XML file, otherwise those functions won't be called.

---

Ok, now that you have the event which ever way you prefer; lets look at how we can make your idea work.

Now, you are asking to switch layouts each time the page changes; this is typically the worst thing to do; but I will answer it first and then give you the alternative method that I use to do complex layouts that work in both Portrait and Landscape modes pretty much automatically.

**MyPage-Landscape.xml**

```
<Page><StackLayout><Label text="Landscape"/></StackLayout></Page>
```

**MyPage-Portrait.xml**

```
<Page><StackLayout><Label text="Portrait"/></StackLayout></Page>
```

**MyPage-Landscape.js**

```
var commonPage = require("./MyPage.js");
var frame = require('ui/frame');
exports.orientation = function(args) {
  if (args.landscape === false) {
     frame.topmost().navigate('MyPage-Portrait');
  }
};

// Tie all the common page code into this pages exports
for (var key in commonPage) {
   if (commonPage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      exports[key] = commonPage[key];
   }
}
```

**MyPage-Portrait.js**

```
var commonPage = require("./MyPage.js");
var frame = require('ui/frame');
exports.orientation = function(args) {
  if (args.landscape === true) {
     frame.topmost().navigate('MyPage-Landscape');
  }
};

// Tie all the common page code into this pages exports
for (var key in commonPage) {
   if (commonPage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      exports[key] = commonPage[key];
   }
}
```

**MyPage.js**

```
exports.TapHandler = function() { /* Someone Tapped */ }
exports.someOtherLogic = function() { /* More logic */ }
exports.etc = function() { /* etc */ }
```

You put all your common page logic in the MyPage file; but you specifically navigate to the specific landscape or portrait page; and each of them are responsible to navigate to the other version if the page orientation changes.

---

Notes about the above solution:

1. You need to navigate to the proper version of the page from any other page; ie. if you are in Landscape mode; when you navigate to another page; you need to make sure you navigate to the Landscaped version of the page.
2. the NS-Orientation plugin does give you a handle helper function to find out the current orientation to make this easier.
3. Remember to make the MyPage.js have all the common code; you want to try and eliminate any custom code on a specific page version.
4. Their is a frame reload command you can use; however it totally clears the history; meaning you can't navigate backwards.  i.e. Page1 -> Page2, frame.reloadPage() means that the back button will NOT go back to Page1.  If this is acceptable; you can make the above system a lot simpler; rather than create separate xml & js files you just need a myPage.landscape.xml and myPage.portrait.xml and you need to on every orientation change just call the frame.reloadPage();

---

Now to me the above is some serious overkill for what is probably a simple change that you need done between pages.  So I'm going to describe how I do it in my apps; which has some pretty complex screens but they look very nice and completely change functionality on a orientation change.

This is part of the reason the NativeScript-orientation plugin was written. On a page orientation change will automatically add / remove a "landscape" class name to the `<Page>` element in your XML.  What this allows you to do in your CSS is:

```
.myLabel {
  font-size: 12;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20;
}

.landscape .myLabel {
  font-size: 16;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40;
}
```

If you haven't figured out where I am going with this; this allows you to have custom CSS for the page while in landscape mode vs it being in portrait mode.  In addition when you use the **exports.orientation** function in union with it also you can then run custom code depending on the orientation.

So in my case; On a phone my scroll list is a single scroll list of items going up down and is sized perfectly to the screen, and looks very sharp.  When you switch to landscape mode; it hides the actionbar, adds a fab button, resizes the entire grid item to fit with the same proportions and switches scrolling modes to right-left.  The majority of the entire look change is done in pure css; and the rest is done in the exports.orientation function which handles things like switching scroll direction.

**Disclaimer: I am the author of the NativeScript-orientation plugin**

Comment: OK, that's a lot of (very useful) information. I already had nativescript-orientation plugin setup and running and it is changing the css. I just haven't managed all the changes in CSS.

I'll look into making the changes programmatically and having only one xml template file, but it will be tricky. For example:

`Gridview columns="*,*,*,*" rows="*" etc`

to

`Gridview columns="*" rows="*,*,*,*" etc`

amongst other things.

Comment: Well, you can use the exports.orientation function to re-setup the gridview programmatically this isn't too hard to do, but you do have to reset any components inside the grid to be tagged to the new layout.  Or depending on how simple the screen is; you can also just have two versions of the gridview and just show/hide the proper one.

Comment: BTW, would be nice to have a Typescript definition file for the plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
}
```

Make sure you have layout XML with same name for both orientations

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml
res/layout-land/my_layout.xml
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Nativescript not android

Answer (score 0):

With correct resource file names Android system automatically reloads your Activities/Fragments with proper resources.
You can catch and handle events manually by setting android:configChanges (but it is a rare case).

Check some documentation:

- [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)
- [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: I've just edited the question to clarify that this is a NativeScript quest.

Comment: I have no experience in NativeScript, but there are same questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908494/does-anybody-know-how-to-detect-orientation-change-for-nativescript

Comment: Detecting is easy, triggering a page reload is not simple. :)